# Forcing 'pass-by-value' through object delegation

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a custom UIControl subclass named 'RotaryWheel'. It is a selection wheel that responds to gestures.

Each selection on the wheel is represented by the following.

```
struct RotaryWheelSectorExternal {

    let section: Int
    let title: String
    var item: Any?

    init(section: Int, title: String, item: Any? = nil) {
        self.section = section
        self.title = title
        self.item = item
    }
}
```

The above is public API, and when consumed, it is represented internally as.

```
struct RotaryWheelSectorInternal {

    let sector: Int
    let minValue: Double
    let midValue: Double
    let maxValue: Double
    let angle: Double
    let title: String
    var item: Any?

}
```

Notice how both of the above struct's contain the same information, however the one is more verbose than the other.

The rotary wheel delegate is loyal to this design, by reporting only the external representation.

```
protocol RotaryWheelControlDelegate: class {
    func rotationEnded(onSector sector: RotaryWheelSectorExternal)
}
```

Of course this requires a conversion of external > internal when the wheel is instantiated and internal > external as the user makes selections and the wheel control reports selections to its delegate.

This doesn't feel right to me but I have been writing Swift long enough to know that the following doesn't feel right either.

```
class RotaryWheelSector {

    let sector: Int
    var minValue: Double?
    var midValue: Double?
    var maxValue: Double?
    var angle: Double?
    let title: String
    var item: Any?

    init...

}
```

This was another option that I considered.

```
class RotaryWheelSectorExternal {

    let section: Int
    let title: String
    var item: Any?

    init(section: Int, title: String, item: Any? = nil) {
        self.section = section
        self.title = title
        self.item = item
    }
}

class RotaryWheelSectorInternal: RotaryWheelSectorExternal {

    let minValue: Double
    let midValue: Double
    let maxValue: Double
    let angle: Double

    init(section: Int, title: String, item: Any?, min: Double, mid: Double, max: Double, angle: Double) {
        self.minValue = min
        self.midValue = mid
        self.maxValue = max
        self.angle = angle
        super.init(section: section, title: title, item: item)
    }

    convenience init(sector: RotaryWheelSectorExternal, min: Double, mid: Double, max: Double, angle: Double) {
        self.init(section: sector.section, title: sector.title, item: sector.item, min: min, mid: mid, max: max, angle: angle)
    }

}
```

However, this doesn't feel right either and I'm not sure which approach to take.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but why not just use one struct and just mark the properties you don't want to expose to the public API as `(file)private` or `internal`?

Comment: No @Hamish once the class is instantiated the min,mid and max values should not change. If the class is instantiated at the public API level then the min, mid and max would need to be set there also. However, the public level is not where those values are available.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating a protocol for the external representation, making the delegate handle an instance of that protocol, and conforming the internal representation struct to the external representation protocol. This allows you to use the same struct instance everywhere (no conversions required), while still not exposing internal properties to the delegate.

Example:

```
fileprivate struct RotaryWheelSectorInternal {

    let sector: Int
    let minValue: Double
    let midValue: Double
    let maxValue: Double
    let angle: Double
    let title: String
    var item: Any?

}

protocol RotaryWheelSectorData {

    let section: Int
    let title: String
    var item: Any?

}

protocol RotaryWheelControlDelegate: class {
    func rotationEnded(onSector sector: RotaryWheelSectorData)
}

extension RotaryWheelSectionInternal : RotaryWheelSectorData { }
```

In this example, the actual `RotaryWheelSectoryInternal` type won't even be visible to other classes, but the `RotaryWheelSectorData` protocol will.  So you can pass an instance of `RotaryWheelSectoryInternal` to the external delegate as an instance of `RotaryWheelSectorData` and thus expose only those properties of the struct.